# Amcharts SerialChart multiple line graphs different category value member paths (Silverlight)

Tags: silverlight, amcharts, linegraph

**EDIT** I rewrote my question to make it more understandable after the conversation below with Tony (thanks!).

**GOAL** Render multiple line graphs (let's say 2) in the same chart. The charts have different x/y value pairs. For one x-value, I do not know both y-values.

I am using Silverlight. The classes available for this are `SerialChart` and `LineGraph`. The data source for both graphs is the same and is set at the `SerialChart` level. The name of the property for the x-axis is also defined there for both graphs (`CategoryValueMemberPath`).

As suggested by the amCharts documentation, we need to create objects that have a property for the category axis (x-axis) and then one property per graph. Let's call them "Graph1" and "Graph2". So the data source looks something like this:

```
List<MyClass> data = new List<MyClass>()
{
   new MyClass() { Category = 0.1, Graph1 = 0.14, Graph2 = ??? }
  ,new MyClass() { Category = 0.15, Graph1 = ???, Graph2 = 0.05 }
  ,new MyClass() { Category = 0.2, Graph1 = 0.35, Graph2 = ??? }
  ,new MyClass() { Category = 0.18, Graph1 = ???, Graph2 = 0.12 }
  ... and so on ...
}
```

**PROBLEM** What am I supposed to do about the "???" values? I do not have the actual value for that graph for that category value.

If I do not set a value, the default value of 0.0 is assumed and it draws a spike to the x-axis. If I set the previously known Graph1/Graph2 value, then it creates a horizontal connection where there is not supposed to be one. I am basically altering the graph which leads to a wrong result.

So how do I solve this? I am getting the feeling that amCharts do not support this scenario.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add two 'value' axes, one in the X direction and one in the Y direction (imagine, like a bubble chart).

```
// AXES
// X
var xAxis = new AmCharts.ValueAxis();
xAxis.position = "bottom";
xAxis.gridAlpha = 0.1;
xAxis.autoGridCount = true;
chart.addValueAxis(xAxis);

// Y
var yAxis = new AmCharts.ValueAxis();
yAxis.position = "left";
yAxis.gridAlpha = 0.1;
yAxis.autoGridCount = true;
chart.addValueAxis(yAxis);
```

Merge all your data points into one array with a common X axis field name ('x' in my example) and for points on line 1, add a property of 'line1' with its value, and for points on line 2, add a property of 'line2'.

For example, your data would look like this:

```
var chartData = [
  {x:0.1,line1:0.25},
  {x:0.246,line1:0.342},

  {x:0.12,line2:0.16},
  {x:0.3,line2:0.485}
];
```

Then add a 'graph' for each line to your chart specifying where to get the value from in the object array.

```
// GRAPHS
var graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
graph.xField = "x";
graph.yField = "line1";
graph.lineAlpha = 1;
graph.lineColor = '#FF9E01';
chart.addGraph(graph);

var graph2 = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
graph2.xField = "x";
graph2.yField = "line2";
graph.lineAlpha = 1;
graph2.lineColor = '#9EFF01';
chart.addGraph(graph2);
```

I've put all this into a Fiddle for you - http://jsfiddle.net/64EWx/

Comment: Hi Tony, thanks for your response. But aren't I still limited by the 'cat' value? I have different 'cat' values for the lines. I would have entries that have: { cat: 0.1, line1: 0.23, line2:<No value>, line3: <no value> } and { cat: 0.12, line1: <No value>, line2: 0.35, line3: <no value>}. To my understanding amCharts are limited by a common category value.

Comment: Its not limited. I've used your example data, which has different cat values for each line

Comment: Thinking about it, the name 'cat' is probably misleading.  I'll change it

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am using Silverlight. It seems as if there are different classes available and AmCharts.AmGraph is not available in the Silverlight version. Only SerialChart and LineGraph.

Comment: I've not used their silverlight charts, but I would imagine the principle is the same.  Create two value axis, add them to the chart then populate the data structure with a x value (common name) and a y value (different name for each line)

Comment: The data source is the same for all line graphs. So I have to provide #null or something like that for the properties that do not have a specific y-value for the current x-value. But when I do that, it interprets it as zero and draws a point at 'x-field' and '0.0'.  If I could provide a data source per line graph, then the problem would be solved. But the data source is global for the entire chart.

Comment: Have a look in the sample code for the X,Y scatter chart type, that will probably do something similar with the data source